# General form of a differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In general, a differential equation can be represented as

$$f(x,y, y', ..., y^{(n)}) = 0$$

is it also then valid to say that a differential equation can be represented as

$$f(x, y) = 0,$$

since $y^{(i)}$ depends entirely on $y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first representation, we have a function $$
f:\Bbb R^{n+2}\to\Bbb R
$$
which is not the case for the second case.
Such functions are far more easy to manipulate than general functionals such as the second equation suggests.

Comment: Is f(x,y) = 0 valid as a general ODE, albeit inefficient then?

Comment: yes, if $f:\Bbb R\times C(\Bbb R, \Bbb R)\to \Bbb R$. People never write such general functionals.